# Problem in changing linear layout back color programmatically

Tags: android

I have a problem in my code.

In this bunch of code I tried to change the background color of linear layout but it not works . The color always sets to grey color !!

```
public static CustomToast makeText(Context context , String message , int duration , ToastType type){
    CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(context);
    ((TextView)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).setText(message);
    ((ImageView)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.imgIcon)).setImageResource(type.getIcon());
    ((LinearLayout)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)).setBackgroundColor(type.getColor());//not work
    toast.getToast().setDuration(duration == 0 ? Toast.LENGTH_SHORT : Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return toast ;
}
```

Comment: what does type.getColor() return?

Comment: it returns an int -> R.color.toastRed

Comment: can you try .setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(type.getColor()))  or .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, type.getColor()))instead and see what happens?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Yes it works tns :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static CustomToast makeText(Context context , String message , int duration , ToastType type){
    CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(context);
    ((TextView)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).setText(message);
    ((ImageView)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.imgIcon)).setImageResource(type.getIcon());    
    ((LinearLayout)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)).setBackgroundColor(type.getColor());  <-- swap this line
    ((LinearLayout)toast.getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)).setBackgroundResource(type.getColor());  <-- with this line
    toast.getToast().setDuration(duration == 0 ? Toast.LENGTH_SHORT : Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return toast ;
}
```

}